# Can't append a list to an existing file

Tags: c#, list, append, file-writing

I have an existing .txt file that I would like to use to store my data, but when using this code I get an error at line 39 at switch case 1.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

class Program
{

    public static List<Pw> Site = new List<Pw>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string file = @"C: \Users\james\Documents\DataFolder\Vault.txt";
        
        string command = "";
        while (command != "exit")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a command: ");
            command = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            switch (command)
            {
                case "1":
                    AddPw();                        
                    File.AppendAllLines(file, Pw.Site);
                    

                    break;
                  
                case "2":
                    
                    if (File.Exists(file))
                    {
                        // Read all the content in one string 
                        // and display the string 
                        string str = File.ReadAllText(file);
                        Console.WriteLine(str);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }


    }
    private static void AddPw()
    {
        Pw pw = new Pw();

        Console.Write("Enter the Username/Email: ");
        pw.Username = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter Full Name: ");
        pw.FullName = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter Phone Number: ");
        pw.PhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.Write("Enter Your Password: ");
        string password = Console.ReadLine();
        pw.Password = password;

        Site.Add(pw);
    }

    private static void PrintPw(Pw pw)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Username/Email: " + pw.Username);
        Console.WriteLine("Full Name: " + pw.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine("Phone Number: " + pw.PhoneNumber);
        Console.WriteLine("Password: " + pw.Password[0]);
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------");
    }

    private static void ListPw()
    {
        if (Site.Count == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your address book is empty. Press any key to continue.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Here are the current people in your address book:\n");
        foreach (var pw in Site)
        {
            PrintPw(pw);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }


         
}

public class Pw
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Welcome, can you please include the error message and tell us what you've already tried? Seems like ```Pw``` doesn't contain a ```Site``` property.

Answer (score 1):

**I have updated your existing function. 

using this function you can add and append data in existing file.**

```
private static void AddPw(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        Pw pw = new Pw();
        if (!File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath))
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the Username/Email: ");
                pw.Username = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.Username);

                Console.Write("Enter Full Name: ");
                pw.FullName = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.FullName);

                Console.Write("Enter Phone Number: ");
                pw.PhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.PhoneNumber);

                Console.Write("Enter Your Password: ");
                pw.Password = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.Password);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(filePath))
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the Username/Email: ");
                pw.Username = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.Username);

                Console.Write("Enter Full Name: ");
                pw.FullName = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.FullName);

                Console.Write("Enter Phone Number: ");
                pw.PhoneNumber = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.PhoneNumber);

                Console.Write("Enter Your Password: ");
                pw.Password = Console.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(pw.Password);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.AppendAllLines(file, Pw.Site);
```

In this line, you need to pass an IEnumerable for AppendAllLines to work.  You can easily convert Site (which is `List<Pw>`) to an `IEnumerable<string>` using the ConvertAll method.  Here's one way of achieving this:

Replace that line with this:

```
File.AppendAllLines(file, Site.ConvertAll<string>(
  (p) => string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}\n", 
    p.Username, 
    p.FullName, 
    p.PhoneNumber, 
    p.Password
  ))
);
```

This "lambda" basically takes your Pw object and converts it into a string inline.